# Blank Fields on the Matching Account during Lead Conversion

Tags: lead-conversion, compact-layout, duplicate-matching-rule

When converting Lead  if a matching Account is found, the compact layout does not display the values. I can't figure out why the values are blank.

[image]

**So far I have check this -**
The fields are populated, the user has read permission to the fields. tested as a System Administrator, checked the compact layout assignment

What I notice is, the record Type of the matched Account found is  'Customer' record type, however the compact layout displayed is not the one assigned to the 'Customer' record type. The one displayed is the primary Compact Layout.

what should I be looking at to with have those fields display values or to ensure, the correct Compact layout is displayed with values ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Setup | Object Manager | Account | Compact Layouts | Compact Layout Assignment` and then `Edit Assignment` to assign your custom compact layout to the record type `Customer`